# is there a description for kernel messages?

Tags: linux, kernel, dmesg

I use dmesg to output kernel messages, but
since I'm new to linux I have no idea what
this informations mean.

Is there a good tutorial or description so
I can understand the messages.

for example:

there are lines which start like:

```
00:00:00.000287 main     Package type: LINUX_64BITS_GENERIC
```

(where to get informations about what "package type" in this context means ?)

and other start with

```
[    5.687092] 00:00:00.002530 main     5.0.16 r105871 started. Verbose level = 0
```

what's the number in [ ...]

what does the time 00:00:.. say

what is a verbose level ?
...

isn't there a description to look this up ?

Answer (score 0):

No, kernel messages are not documented. They are generally meant for developers or experienced system administrators. Few are of interest to ordinary users, and unfortunately they are not singled out.

The way to find what a kernel message means is generally to find the location in the source code ([LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) can help) or to find a message or page on the Internet that mentions it.

I'm not familiar with this particular message but a web search suggests that it doesn't come from the kernel at all, but from VirtualBox.